# Is there a way to turn off default crit damage rolls in roll20?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, dice, critical-hit, roll20

I have a crit table I use for random crit events. The table is recursive and triggers whenever a 20 is rolled, but the default programming in Roll20 also rolls the additional damage roll that's built into the same roll by default. I would prefer to have it just roll on the crit table and remove the additional damage roll.

Is it possible to remove the additional damage roll and have Roll20 just reference the crit table?

Comment: As written, you question is a bit broad by virtue of, "Anybody have any suggestions." Can you elaborate on what you've tried and your familiarity with Roll20? Do you need the system to still notify when a critical hit occurs? Also, you indicate that you're using the 5e system; does your table only care about critical hits or natural 20's, there are some features that permit crits on 19.

Comment: To clarify my intent, it'll help us answer correctly if you can better define what you're shooting for as narrowly as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time phrasing exactly it is that I want. I have a little recursive table macro that triggers a random crit event on natural 20's (only natural 20's) and my players have been confused by the additional damage die that gets auto rolled whenever he/she gets a natural 20. I still want the system to let me know when a natural 20 has been rolled. I've looked through the roll20 settings and it's 100% possible I'm just totally missing something obvious.

Comment: Just made substantial edits to try and get at your intent. If that works for you great, if not you can either edit further or rollback.

Comment: Logan can you confirm if my answer below is on the right path. If not I will remove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any of the character sheets within Roll20, under the 'Character Sheet Tab' you should see a small settings cog on the right hand side.

Upon clicking that, you should be given various settings options. On the right-hand side box (with the 'NPC' Tick box), there is a small drop down menu titled **Auto Damage Roll**. When you click this, it allows you to turn on or off the option to automatically roll damage (including critical damage).

Thus when you roll, it will only roll the attack roll. You can then either manually roll the damage, or click the name of the attack (in chat) which will roll the damage for you.

I am unsure if all Roll20 character sheets have this feature, but I know the default ones do.

[image: Roll20 5E inspired Sheet, Settings Page]

Comment: Logan Clemons - is this anywhere close to what you have requested?

Comment: I don't see anything in there dealing with auto crit rolls.

Comment: Hi Logan on the right hand box, underneath Whisper Rolls to Gm there is an Option to Auto Roll Damage and Crit, you cna turn this off as it is a drop down menu, however this would affect only the character attached to that sheet.

Comment: Not a problem, if you still have issues, go to my profile and message me on Twitter I use Roll20 a lot Either that or I can add you on Discord.

Comment: @LoganClemons, if this answered your question, you should give the responder the check mark to indicate as such. Both you and the respondent will gain additional rep and others that find this question later will benefit from knowing that this worked for you.